# curl displaying all 302s (and 303s) found

Tags: curl

I can make `curl` follow a redirection, but how can I make `curl` show me all indirections while retrieving the final page?

For example, if I request `http://so.com/page1.html` and `so` redirects to `so1`, which redirects to `so2`, how can I see the chain of 302s until I finally get the page from `http://so2.com/page1.htm'`?